# Advice on creating java onscreen keyboard

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to create a onscreen keyboard such that when a text field gets focused the keyboard appears on the screen and when the focus is lost or if one clicks outside the screen the keyboard should disappear.

This is not the problem, the problem is that i'm not sure what I should use to create such a keyboard. I cannot use a `jFrame` because if I click outside the keyboard window then the keyboard goes to the background and is not closed.  I also can't use `jDialog` because it do not allow us to click outside the window.

I also would like to be able to show a textbox with what is entered by the keyboard in real-time(as i click the keys on the onscreen keyboard it should appear in the textbox). I am doing this program in netbeans so if you could keep that in mind, it would be helpful.

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Swing-AWT/6311-virtual-onscreen-keyboard-project-using-java-and-swings.html

Comment: Man, how could we have an idea where to start? Show us what you´ve tried so far.

Comment: *"please let me know if there is a easy way in netbeans."* If Java can do it, so can Netbeans.  BTW - I can think of 14 possible questions you might ask based on completing this task.  Which one are you asking?

Comment: @Hans go ahead, elaborate on in which container the keyboard should be placed and how animations could be done and turn the provided link into an answer as this is the stuff OP wants.

Comment: it's amazing what google can do sometimes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the requirement here, but see if this example gives you some ideas.

The basic thrust of it is to ensure there is 'white space' (OK `RED`/`ORANGE` in this example, but let's not quibble over shades of gray) around the components that can become focusable.  Add a mouse listener to it, and on event, request the focus (or in your case, hide the keyboard).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ComponentFocus {

    ComponentFocus() {
        final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,15,15));
        gui.setFocusable(true);
        gui.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override 
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                System.out.println(me);
                gui.requestFocus(true);
            }
        });
        gui.setBackground(Color.RED);
        gui.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                gui.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
                gui.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        });

        JButton button1 = new JButton("button1");
        gui.add(button1);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("button2");
        gui.add(button2);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ComponentFocus();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: notice FocusListener and HierarchyListener are asyncronous +1

Comment: thanks andrew but its not helping because its behaving like a jDialog as i said i need the keyboard window such that if the user click the area outside the window the keyboard exits (in jDialog if we click outside the window then we hear a sound "ting" and we are unable to click on the outside till we close the dialog)

Comment: @Sar009 for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), anything else could be only shots to the dark

Comment: *"its behaving like a jDialog"*  It won't when you put the red/orange panel in a frame, which is what I meant!  But agree with @mKorbel you'll get more help on this, only if I see an SSCCE of your best attempt.